# Partial derivatives of a homogeneous function with degree $n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 →\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function. Answer the following questions:

1. Assume that $∀(x, y) ∈$ $\mathbb R^2$ and $∀t ∈$ $\mathbb R$, $f(x + t, y + t) = f(x, y)$.

Show that $\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂x}  + \frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂y} = 0$.

2. Assume that $f$ is homogeneous with degree $n$, i.e $∀(x, y) ∈$ $\mathbb R^2$ and $∀t ∈$ $\mathbb R$,
   $f(tx, ty) = t^n f(x, y)$.

Show that $x\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂x} + y\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂y} = nf(x, y)$

I tried working on these two problems for more than an hour but I still didn't get the correct answer. In part 1,I let $u=x+t$ and $v=y+t$, and so by the chain rule, I got that $\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂x} =\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂u}. \frac{∂u}{∂x} = \frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂u}$

And $\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂y} = \frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂v}. \frac{∂v}{∂y} = \frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂v}$. But how to continue from there?

In part 2, I let $u=tx$ and $v=ty$ and so by chain rule,$\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂x} =\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂u}. \frac{∂u}{∂x} + \frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂v}. \frac{∂v}{∂x} = t. \frac{∂f}{∂u}$

And $\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂y} =\frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂u}. \frac{∂u}{∂y} + \frac{∂f(x, y)}{∂v}. \frac{∂v}{∂y} = t. \frac{∂f}{∂v}$. But how to continue from there?

Any help in the 2 parts please?

Comment: *Hint:* Differentiate the identities with respect to $t$.

Comment: (1) Take derivative in the given equation with respect to $t$. The right hand side has derivative $0$, since it doesn't depend on $t$. The left hand side has derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x+t,y+t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x+t,y+t)=0$ by the chain rule. Evaluating at $t=0$ you get your equation.

Comment: Why? How would this help me?

Comment: (2) Same idea as (1). $x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(tx,ty)+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(tx,ty)=nt^{n-1}f(x,y)$, but now you evaluate at $t=1$ instead.

Comment: Take into account the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(g(x,y,t),h(x,y,t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(g(x,y,t),h(x,y,t))\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(x,y,t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(g(x,y,t),h(x,y,t))\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h(x,y,t)$$ In (1) you apply this with $g(x,y,t)=x+t$ and $h(x,y,t)=y+t$, while in (2) you apply it with $g(x,y,t)=tx$ and $h(x,y,t)=ty$.

Comment: Please could you show me how

Comment: In (1), since $g(x,y,t)=x+t$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(x,y,t)=1$. Likewise, since $h(x,y,t)=y+t$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h(x,y,t)=1$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x+t,y+t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x+t,y+t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x+t,y+t)$.

Comment: Yess, now I see thank you!